# Full Path of Loaded Dlls?

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I am trying to debug some shared library problems on a machine with dozens of shared libraries with the same name. I need to find the one .dll out of 10 identically names file that is working correctly.

When we moved computers the program seems to load the wrong dll.

On the working computer I want to figure out exactly which dll the program choose. I was able to get the name of the dll displayed but not the full path.

Does anybody know how to display the full path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do actually want to download and run [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). Opening your application in this program will display all its dependencies, show their paths (and you can display the full paths) and reveal those DLLs it can't find.

If some of your DLLs are loaded dynamically, just use the profile option to actually execute the application.

[image: Depency Walker Profile Option]

This will additionally show those dependencies which are loaded at a later stage within your program.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

This will let you see loaded DLLs (even dynamically loaded ones), as well as other useful information such as sockets, security, environment variables, threads and strings, all without launching a debugger.